# echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) from inside PHP echo

Tags: php, html

i'm trying to create some dynamic content using php so i am echoing html code into my webpage. However when i try to insert a `<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>` inside an action tag inside a form, unwanted visible text is printed onto my page most likely due to some sort of parsing error.

my example is as follows below.

```
echo'<form name="PArtifact" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
     <input name="printArtifactBut" type="submit"  value="Print Artifact">                
     </form>';
```

The code above will produce "> as visible text. Can someone tell me the correct way to echo `htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])` inside an echo?

Comment: Don't bother.  The default form action is already your current page, just leave it without an action attribute.

Comment: Why do you have `<?php` inside `echo`? **Edit:** What I mean is, if it's an `echo`, it doesn't need `<?php echo`, or if you are using `<?php`, you don't need the echo in the beginning.

Comment: This is because i'm dynamically creating a button which will recall the page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already have PHP opened and you are already inside of an echo expression.  You just need to [concatenate](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) the data:

```
echo '<form name="PArtifact" method="post" action="' . htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) . '"></form>';
```

But as I said in the comments, this is unnecessary because the form action is already this by default.

---

Other way to achieve what you mean is exit php section:

```
?>
<form name="PArtifact" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
  <input name="printArtifactBut" type="submit"  value="Print Artifact">                
</form>
<?php
```

Comment: Thank you, this fixed the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is down to a fundamental misunderstanding of how PHP works. There is absolutely no need to have an echo inside an echo; the very concept is a non-sequitur. If you need to call a function within an echo, simply close the string being echo'ed, append the function call to the string using a dot. Then another dot afterward, open the string again with another quote, and carry on where you left off.

```
echo'<form name="PArtifact" method="post" action="' . htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) . '">
 <input name="printArtifactBut" type="submit"  value="Print Artifact">                
 </form>';
```

However in this case, as others have said already, you don't really even need to do this, as the use of `PHP_SELF` in a form's `action` attribute is redundant -- that is the default value for `action` anyway. So for this case you can simply leave that whole bit out:

```
echo'<form name="PArtifact" method="post" action="">
 <input name="printArtifactBut" type="submit"  value="Print Artifact">                
 </form>';
```

...and you'll have exactly the same effect that you were wanted anyway.